# Distribution of elements of inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Suppose $M$ is an $n \times n$ matrix whose elements are independent random values that follow a normal distribution whose mean is $0$ and whose standard deviation is $1$. What distribution will the elements of $M^{-1}$ follow? If the distribution of $M$ follows a uniform distribution, how does this change the distribution of the elements of $M^{-1}$? To clarify, $M$ is [almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely) an invertible matrix simply because of the way it's generated. When you have a matrix filled with independent random real values, it's almost surely invertible even if it's really large.

Comment: Who told $M$ is invertible?

Comment: It even has a non-null probability of being non-invertible. ^^ I wouldn't try this for $n>1$ at home.

Comment: @Qwerty it is almost surely invertable.

Comment: It's almost surely going to be invertible.

Comment: How about choosing a distribution that doesn't put so much probability near 0? Even for $n = 1$ it's problematic. [If $Z \sim NORM(0,1),$ then the distribution of $1/Z$ is ill-behaved.]

Comment: For $n = 2$, finding the averages of elements in $10^5$ inverses of $2\times 2$ matrices with elements dist'd as UNIF(1,2), I got
min = -119, Q1 = .1439, Med = 0.1650, Q3 = 10.14, Max = 416.3.

Comment: From simulations it seems that the elements of the inverted matrix are also distributed normally (although with another variance). For $2\times 2$ matrices, it is easy to see that the elements are indeed normally distributed, as there is an explicit formula for such an inverse.